# After updating python version, old downloaded packages not working in vsc when using jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I updated my python version to latest in my WSL and now when running the latest kernel version with Visual Studio Code jupyter extension it cannot regognize the packages I have downloaded from pip with the earlier version.

With the earlier version (3.8.10) when I run

```py
import torch
```

all goes normal, but when using (3.11.0)
It says:

```
No module named 'torch'
```

I tried to download the packages from pip again and it seems to work but do I really have to do it with every package I have used with the earlier version or can I in some way update the packages or something?

Comment: This is how python works, packages depend on specific python versions, and are installed into python specific version package paths.

Comment: Yeah, I just reinstalled the packages since that was the way they work. Will make virtual env for every python version from now on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good practice is to have virtual env for each python version, using Anaconda or pipenv.
in your case you may change the python path to the new version
in you `.bashrc` file

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/[path to new version]
```

source .bashrc and you good to go
you can now install packages to the new version